# Is there any way we can click on a button random times using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

How to click on an element random times using selenium. Is it possible to that using selenium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple `loop` for this in which you use the `click()` method to click on the button on each iteration.

```
WebElement button = // Find your element here
Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(50);
while n > 0 {
    button.click();
    n--;
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error "elementId 4 could not be tapped"